# sequencing epics in redux

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have two epics, epicA and epicB.

B is subject to back-pressure since the api calls associated with it are slower. (uploads)

However, I need to make sure that all of the api requests that come from B complete before A.

so if the requests are

`B1....A1....B2...B3...`

If B1 has not completed by the time that B2 fires, the resolution should be

`B1, B2, B3, A1`

If B1 completes before B2 is fired, resolution should be

`B1, A1, B2, B3`

I thought at first that

```
const bigEpic = epicA.concat(epicB)
```

would be an answer, but I don't think that makes sense

Another idea:

```
const bigEpic = action$ => epicA(action$).concat(epicB(action$))
```

Comment: If you reword your question to be just rxjs without redux-observable lingo you should get a lot more answers :) nearly all redux-observable questions are actually just rxjs

Comment: Does this boil down to an rxjs question? Since I'm declaring some process hierarchy, I haven't found patterns that resolve two epics this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Observable.merge` for sequencing actions.

```
const fetchFirst = () =>
  (action, store) => Observable.ajax('/first');

const fetchSecond = () =>
  (action, store) => Observable.ajax('/second');

const fetchBoth = () =>
  (action, store) =>
    Observable.merge(
      fetchFirst()(action, store),
      fetchSecond()(action, store),
   )
```